# SQL query that produces the following output?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database

I am trying to write an SQL statement producing the below output.
I have the two following tables:

**UserMovie**

```
userID | movieID
-----------------
  135  |  k0jps
  135  |  p1zka
  125  |  v0t67
  115  |  opp2s
  111  |  xnwri
  115  |  kspdl
```

**Follows**

```
followerid | followingid
------------------------
    122    |     135  
    192    |     111
    125    |     240
    120    |     125
    45     |     111
```

I want to fetch the number of followers of each user who's userid is in the UserMovie Table, giving the following result:

**Result**

```
userid | followerCount
----------------------
  135  |       1
  125  |       1
  115  |       0
  111  |       2
```

The following statement gives me partially what i want:

```
SELECT followingid, count(*) as followerCount   
FROM Follows   
WHERE followingid in (SELECT DISTINCT userID FROM UserMovie)   
GROUP BY followingid
```

The issue with the above query is that users with 0 followers do not appear in the results giving the following output:

```
userid | followerCount
----------------------
  135  |       1
  125  |       1
  111  |       2
```

Any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to include users with no follows:

```
SELECT  UserId, Count(followerid) AS followerCount
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT userId FROM UserMovie ) m
LEFT JOIN Follows f
ON f.followingid = m.userID
GROUP BY UserId
```

Now it generates :

```
UserId  followerCount
111 2
115 0
125 1
135 1
```

Comment: Giving wrong answer. I think something's wrong with your join.

Comment: i am not sure who follows who in your follow table. try change the followngid.

Comment: followerid follows followingid

Comment: Sorry didn't notice that you don't have an user table with unique userid. Changed the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach: get a distinct list of `userID` from `UserMovie` in an inline view (use either a `GROUP BY` or a `DISTINCT` keyword), and perform an "outer join" operation of that to the `Followers` table to find followers. Collapse the rows from that with a `GROUP BY`, and use an aggregate function to get a count of unique/distinct non-null values of `userId` from the `Followers` table.

For example:

```
SELECT u.userID
     , COUNT(DISTINCT f.userID) AS cnt_followers
  FROM ( SELECT m.userID
           FROM UserMovie m
          GROUP BY m.userID
       ) u
  LEFT
  JOIN Follows f
    ON f.followingid = u.userID
 GROUP BY u.userID
```

**EDIT**

There's an invalid column reference in the SELECT list,  `f.userID` is not valid.  That should be `f.followerID`.

When we fix that, the query returns:

```
userID  cnt_followers
111     2
115     0
125     1
135     1
```

[SQL Fiddle **HERE** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de3e7/2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de3e7/2)

As long as we are counting "distinct" followerid (question doesn't give any guarantee that `(followerID,followingID)` is UNIQUE in `Followers` table), we could eliminate the inline view

```
SELECT u.userID
     , COUNT(DISTINCT f.userID) AS cnt_followers
  FROM UserMovie u
  LEFT
  JOIN Follows f
    ON f.followingid = u.userID
 GROUP BY u.userID
```

Comment: This is correctly inserting 0s but giving a wrong value for the number of followers of users whose num of followers > 0

Comment: The reference to `f.userID` in my query is invalid. That should be `f.followerID`. SQL Fiddle demonstration added.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me.
However I am getting NULLs instead of 0 for users with no followers

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.userid, t.followerCount   
FROM UserMovie u  
LEFT JOIN (   
SELECT followingid, count(*) AS followerCount      
FROM Follows      
WHERE followingid in (SELECT DISTINCT userID FROM UserMovie)      
GROUP BY followingid ) as t   
on t.followingid = u.userid
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a solution using CASE?

```
SELECT userId,
CASE
  WHEN IFNULL(followerid, 0) = 0 THEN 0
  ELSE count(*)
END
FROM UserMovie
LEFT JOIN Follows on followingid=userID
GROUP BY userId;
```

Seems to work fine in SQLite3, just replace IFNULL with ISNULL (if SQLServer) or any other equivalent. It's pretty similar to what you've done.

Comment: Note that UserMovie's PK is the combination (UserID + MovieID) and not UserID itself (can have multiple entries)

Comment: There's no need for a `CASE` expression. The query will return the specified result if we replace the `CASE` expression with **`COUNT(DISTINCT Follows.followerID)`**.  (Yes, the `followerID` column will be NULL when a matching row isn't found, but we don't need a `CASE` to hanle that, `COUNT` starts at zero and increments for non-NULL values. The `DISTINCT` keyword, inside the `COUNT()` means any "duplicated" values won't be included in the count, each unique value will be increment the count by one.)